# Can data.table functions manipulate date and time columns on the fly?

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I have started using data.table. Indeed it is very fast and quite nice syntax. I am having trouble with dates. I like to use lubridate. In many of my data sets I have dates or dates and times and have used lubridate to manipulate them. Lubridate stores the instant as a POSIX class. I have seen answers here that create new variables for instance just to get the year eg. 2005. I do not like that. There are times that I will be analyzing by year and other times by quarter and other times by month and other times by durations. I would like to do something simple such as this

```
mydatatable[,length(medical.record.number),by=year(date.of.service)]
```

that should give me the number of patient encounters in a given year. The by function is not working.

```
Error in names(byval) = as.character(bysuborig) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Can you please point me to vignettes where data.tables is used with dates and where manipulations and categorizations of those dates are done on the fly.

Comment: DWin's answer is right: change `date.of.service` to an `IDateTime`. Will aim to improve that cryptic error message to give that advice directly in the error message in future (or just make it work for POSIXct). New [FR#1668](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1668&group_id=240&atid=978) added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses one of the examples in the `help(IDateTime)` page. It shows that you canc hange to syntax for the `by=`argument to a character value in the form " = " or (after @Matthew Dowle's comment below) you can try to use the functional form that you were using (although I have not been able to get it to work myself. I did get the preferred form: `by=list(wday=wday(idate))` to work.) Note that the key creation assumes an IDateTime class since there is no `idate` or `itime` variable. Those are attributes of the class

```
datetime <- seq(as.POSIXct("2001-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2001-01-03"), by = "5 hour")    
(af <- data.table(IDateTime(datetime), a = rep(1:2, 5), key = "a,idate,itime"))

 af[, length(a), by = "wday = wday(idate)"]
         wday V1
[1,]    2  4
[2,]    3  5
[3,]    4  1
```

Comment: `IDateTime` is the way to go, yes, but the character form of `by` is a red herring. Farrel's syntax would work fine if the column class were `IDateTime`; e.g. just `by=year(idate)` or `by=wday(idate)`. The character form of `by` is there as a legacy option. `by=list(wday=wday(idate))` is now the preferred way to name `by` columns (and multiple `by` columns). Will update the documentation re those examples, thanks ...

Comment: Yip. Those inverted commas (quotation marks) solved the problem. I have quite a lot of date fields across all of my research. Most of my scripts read them and convert them to POSIXct. They then become part of several dataframes that I use from time to time. Does that mean when I want to use data.tables I should convert all of the date columns to IDate?